# does using malloc( ) inside a function free the allocated memory after its execution?

Tags: c

when trying to print the values of struct variables after the function returns it prints some random text (which I think is due to memory allocation error)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char s1[20];
    char s2[20];
    int n1;
} TEST;

void allocate(TEST *T, int n){
    T = malloc(sizeof(TEST)*n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        sprintf((T+i)->s1, "string 1 of %d", i);
        sprintf((T+i)->s2, "string 2 of %d", i);
        (T+i)->n1 = i;
    }
}

int main(){

    TEST *T;
    int n = 3;
    allocate(T, n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%s\n%s\n%d\n\n", (T+i)->s1, (T+i)->s2, (T+i)->n1);
    }

}
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is exactly equal to `*(p + i)`. From that follows that instead of e.g. `(T + i)->n1` you could do `T[i].n1`. Which is often easier to read and understand, as well as less to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by the already given answers you need to call `free` to free the memory.

You want to allocate the pointed memory area, so you need a `TEST**`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char s1[20];
    char s2[20];
    int n1;
} TEST;

void allocate(TEST **T, int n){
    *T = malloc(sizeof(TEST)*n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        sprintf((*T+i)->s1, "string 1 of %d", i);
        sprintf((*T+i)->s2, "string 2 of %d", i);
        (*T+i)->n1 = i;
    }
}

int main(){

    TEST *T;
    int n = 3;
    allocate(&T, n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%s\n%s\n%d\n\n", (T+i)->s1, (T+i)->s2, (T+i)->n1);
    }
    free(T);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, C absolutely does not call `free` automatically for you.

The issue in your program is that `T` in the caller to `allocate` is not changed. C is strictly a *pass by value* language.

One solution is to change the type of T to `TEST**` in `allocate`:

```
void allocate(TEST **T, int n){
```

with

```
allocate(&T, n);
```

in `main`. You then call `free` in `main`.

Comment: As an alternative, one could return the pointer instead of emulating pass by reference.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Or implement a Boehm garbage collector!

Answer (score 1):

No. The problem with your program is that T is passed by copy to allocate, and the address to the allocated memory is assigned to this copy. To fix, you could make the first allocate parameter **T, pass in the address of T in main, and dereference the pointer to pointer in allocate and assign to it.

Answer (score 1):

The program causes undefined behaviour by passing uninitialized `T` to the function. Furthermore you never return the new pointer value from the function back to `main`.

The pointer to new memory is an *output* of the function, not an *input*. So it should be a return value, not a parameter. For example:

```
TEST* allocate(int n)
{
    TEST* T = malloc(sizeof(TEST)*n);
    // etc.
    return T;
}
```

and then in main:

```
TEST* T = allocate(n);
// ... use T ...
free(T);
```

Answer (score -1):

No, it doesn't. You need to `free()` `malloc()`ated memory yourself.

Your program, as is, leaks memory... but for this particular program it doesn't matter an awful lot since that memory is freed when the process dies.